# install package from debian backports pool

Tags: debian, apt, dovecot, patch-management

I want to upgrade my dovecote installation to version 2. I discovered the package [here](http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports/pool/main/d/dovecot/). I also already added `deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main` to my `sources.list`. But the desired package inside the `pool` directory. How can i access there packages via `apt`? I'm using debian squeeze

Comment: You should be good already with that line in `sources.list`. Did you do `apt-get update` after adding it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use the following line for backports:

```
deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main contrib non-free
```

After you added the backports to sources.list make sure to run:

```
apt-get update
```

Then in order to install a package from backports you run:

```
apt-get -t squeeze-backports install examplename
```

The option ***-t squeeze-backports*** tells apt to specifically use backports for that package. It then will also pull any dependencies that are present in backports from backports. Not using the ***-t*** option could work, in case the package name does not exist in squeeze (for example linux-image-3.2.0-0.bpo.2-amd64) AND the install does not depend on packages that also have to be pulled from backports.

Also remember that as far as I know backports packages do not automatically update through a regular update (such as apt-get upgrade). You would have to run the above command again for each package in order to pull in a possible newer backported version.

Answer (score 3):

Try to do a search at first:

```
apt-cache -t squeeze-backports search a_fancy_package
```

and then choose the exact name of a package from the list

```
apt-get install -t squeeze-backports the_fancy_package
```

I'd do it like this:

```
apt-cache -t squeeze-backports search dove | grep -v ice
```

and then probably

```
apt-get install -t squeeze-backports dovecot-core dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d
```

and whatever else you need.